# Cannot make ConEmu the default terminal console on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, terminal, cmd.exe, console, conemu

I have ComEmu64 installed on Win 10 Pro 1903.  Originally I had it installed through Chocolatey but have also tried downloading and installing manually.

First of all I should point out I was having issues with it starting up with Windsows so I had to add it to the Task Scheduler.  However this issue seems to persist even if manually relaunched.  I also have Windows set to use Powershell and I have a default Powershell admin tab open in ConEmu at launch.

Here is my Default Console Setting in ConEmu:

[image: Settings Window]

I have gone to the site linked in the bottom and unless I don't understand something I have set it up properly.  I have also seen some solutions that say changing the CompSec setting in the System Properties Enviromental Variables to ConEmu's executable could also do it.  It doesn't

Anything run from the Run Window, Classic Start Menu, the Start Menu, or (when I have it enabled) Wox does not go to ConEmu even if I add their executable to the settings for ConEmu.  I have tried ipconfig /all , ping 8.8.8.8 , and Choco upgrade all -y (for something not shell based) and all open in a regular console window and close when done.  Meanwhile shells inside ConEmu work fine, but do not  pick up consoles.  I have also tried a game server I am familiar with that launches in a console to see it that would be picked up by ConEmu and it wasn't.

I have gotten this to work in the past but most of the time I just go into ConEmu so did not notice this issue until last night, when of course, I wanted to get it to work on something that launches a console.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have 1903 yet. Most probably Microsoft changed something that prevent DefTerm from working. You may use log files to determine what happens. But that is not a question for SU due to supposed long conversation. Doesn't DefTerm work when ConEmu is started manually?

Comment: No, not at all.  Also to be clear This was happening before 1903, I just thought I had forgot to set it as default.

Also what do you mean not a question for SuperUser?  I am new to the community but this wasn't in the joining info.  Also coming from a technician/EUS background I was trying to be thorough to give any info people may need to help.  Not trying to sound aggro... genuinely asking.

Comment: @WolvenSpectre I am not sure what Maximus is specifically referencing, but under the [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) guide regarding what makes a "bad" question, there is a general warning against "Chatty, open-ended questions" (though ones that produce "lengthy" answers aren't specifically prohibited). There is also a general prohibition against having long conversations in the comments.